# How can I highlight a node in Slate js v0.47

Tags: editor, syntax-highlighting, rich-text-editor, slate.js

I want to highlight some text nodes in the editor. I do have the keys and paths of the nodes I want to highlight. How can I do that in older version of Slate js (v0.47 or below).
The text needs to be highlighted on the load, and the nodes are not in Selection as well. I want to highlight the text by giving it a light background color.